# How to set Custom User Property in keycloak from java api

Tags: java, authentication, spring-security, keycloak, keycloak-services

I am using keycloak for authentication in my spring application, how can I set some attribute for a user. 
I have already added a custom mapper on admin console.

Comment: What have you tried? What do you exactly want?

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look below attached screen shot,in user section there is the tab where you can set the attributes

[image]

Now question will be how you will access those user attributes through code?

So here is the code which can be use to access user attributes .

```
HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
        KeycloakSecurityContext securityContext = (KeycloakSecurityContext) httpRequest.getAttribute(KeycloakSecurityContext.class.getName());
          AccessToken accessToken = securityContext.getToken();
          if(null != accessToken ){
          Map<String, Object> otherClaims = accessToken.getOtherClaims() ;     
          tgtToken = securityContext.getTokenString();
          String firstUserAtt = otherClaims.get("First_User_Attribute").toString();
          String secondUserAtt = otherClaims.get("Second_User_Attribute").toString();
}
```

Note - `First_User_Attribute`,`Second_User_Attribute` are the key you declare in the keycloak's user attribute section.